# Check box by default, if unchecked, stay unchecked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox with this code

```
<td align="right">Include In Top Sellers?</td>
                          <td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="include_top"
                            value="0"><input type="checkbox"
                            name="include_top"
                            id="include_top"
                            value="1" <?php echo (($_POST["include_top"] == "1") or ($res["include_top"] == "1")) ? "checked='checked'" : ""; ?>
                            autocomplete="off"/>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
```

I need to have this box checked by default but also allow it to be unchecked and stay unchecked if saved.

Comment: when you uncheck and save it, it stays checked?

Answer (score 1):

This is how to start with a checked checkbox

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked>Checkbox</input>
```

Comment: Beat me to it! @MHeredia If you uncheck it, I'm fairly certain that it will be unchecked when saved.

Comment: Correct. I had this but it stays checked even after unchecking and saving.

Comment: @ChrisHappy unfortunately it doesn't because the code exists in a .php template file

Comment: I suppose your problem is in the code structure, it can't stay checked if you uncheck it

Comment: Definitely staying checked. Care to look at my entire php file?

Answer (score 0):

make a jquery activated from isset PHP

ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function uncheck(){$(#includ_top).attr('checked', false)}</script>
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{<script>uncheck();</script>}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can not have 2 input elements with same name `include_top`.
2. Output your `$_POST["include_top"]` and `$res["include_top"]` to see which one make that condition to true.

A sample code is like this:

```
                      <td>
                        <!--input type="hidden" name="include_top"
                        value="0"-->
                       <?php var_dump($_POST["include_top"], $res["include_top"]); ?>
                        <input type="checkbox"
                        name="include_top"
                        id="include_top"
                        value="1" <?php echo (($_POST["include_top"] == "1") or ($res["include_top"] == "1")) ? "checked='checked'" : ""; ?>
                        autocomplete="off"/>
                      </td>
```

3. If you want it default to true, you should be better check reversely like this:

   ```
   <?php echo (($_POST["include_top"] != "1") and ($res["include_top"] != "1")) ? "" : "checked='checked'"; ?>
   ```